# File not saved to internal storage (no IOException)

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I am trying to save text into internal storage (world readable) on android. However, the file is not saved (the folder as well is not created).

What I expect:
- file of name '20170323_003033' saved under '.../android/data/my.package.name/' in internal storage

What happens:
- Neither file nor directory my.package.name exists

I verified that the file/directory does not exist by checking under the ../android/data folders in both internal and external storage, as well as running a search for the partial file name '20170323'.

The relevant code in question:

```
private void saveInternalFile() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String coords;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        if (location != null) {
            coords = GpxUtils.getDMS(location.getLatitude(), GpxUtils.LATITUDE) + GpxUtils.getDMS(location.getLongitude(), GpxUtils.LONGITUDE);
            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(timeStamp, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                outputStream.write(coords.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved as " + timeStamp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, in catching the IOException I did both `printStackTrace` as well as `System.exit(0)`. Since I received neither a stack trace nor did the app quit, I am quite sure the code in the try block ran successfully. The toast showed as expected.

Logcat shows no errors for the onclick for the button that triggers this method (showing verbose log):

```
03-23 01:44:38.376 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-23 01:44:38.506 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-23 01:44:38.576 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{4fd08dd V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-23 01:44:38.626 11842-11934/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [763x176]-format:1
03-23 01:44:38.626 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-23 01:44:38.666 11842-11934/io.ningyuan.gpslogger V/RenderScript: 0x7f825f4000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
03-23 01:44:38.676 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-23 01:44:40.556 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
03-23 01:44:40.576 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{5e4c52 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
03-23 01:44:40.606 11842-11934/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [599x176]-format:1
03-23 01:44:40.606 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-23 01:44:40.616 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-23 01:44:42.576 11842-11842/io.ningyuan.gpslogger D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Comment: Try logging the return value of getFileStreamPath(timeStamp). This should give you the absolute path where openFileOutput will create the file. It may be creating the file in a different location than the one you expect.

Comment: "as well as running a search for the partial file name '20170323'" -- um, how exactly are you doing this? After all, users (including you) do not have much in the way of direct access to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: @joep Thanks for the feedback. I added `Log.i("saveInternalFile", getFileStreamPath(timeStamp).getAbsolutePath());` to the method. The logcat shows `03-23 03:06:04.036 29189-29189/io.ningyuan.gpslogger I/saveInternalFile: /data/user/0/io.ningyuan.gpslogger/files/20170323_030603`, but the directory does not exist through the both the pc and phone's native file explorer. I think you're on to something though, since there is another app using this directory in the form of `/data/user/0/com.samsung..../files/...xml`

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm running the app on android studio on my physical smartphone rather than emulated device. The only two ways I know of to navigate the storage is through the native android file explorer, or windows explorer. I'm still very new at this though, is there a better way?

Comment: "The only two ways I know of to navigate the storage is through the native android file explorer, or windows explorer" -- neither of those can access internal storage. They access [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and in some cases [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare I think you have a point here. I may be misunderstanding the difference between internal, external, and removable storage.

Comment: Yeah, what users think those terms mean differs from how the Android SDK uses the terms. And even the SDK Is inconsistent. Use `openFileInput()` (and internal storage in general) for files that the user should not be able to access. Use external storage (and possibly removable storage) for stuff the user should be able to access independently.